# I Have configured a DNS Server and have a domain now

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos, domain, bind

So, I configured BIND on 2 of my servers. I have BIND fully working.
I changed my DNS on my Computer to my master server. I then visited the domain I setup. it seems to work. but once I'm not connected using my DNS it does not work. Is there some place on the internet where I have to submit my name-servers?

Sorry for such a noob question. I have searched the internet for hours and could not find anything.

I'm new at hosting my own DNS and domains.

Comment: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.

Comment: Also, there's so much information on the subject on the Internet (even on this very site) that hours of research should have given at least something to start with. Frankly, if it didn't, you should have someone else to do it for you.

Comment: Yes, you need to yell your registrar for the domain you want to host what the name servers are. Read their docs. But really, don't. The registrar will most likely offer free hosting of the domain in its own DNS servers and they will be magnitudes more competent to do so then yourself. If they don't offer DNS services, switch registrars - plenty available.

Comment: Your question will be likely closed, but you will be probably more successful on https://superuser.com .

Answer (score 1):

It is like a telephone, you know.

YOu can set up your own telephone system hoever you like, but once you want other people to reach you, you need to tie into the large telephone network.

SImilar.

You can come up with all kinds of domains - but once you want other people to reach them, you must register them officially. WHich is SO much marketed on every internet provider ever if you say "i have searched the internet for hours" I wonder if you ever heard of google.